# Can someone translate this Java regex to Python?

Tags: java, python, regex

Regex in Java is `\A[a-zA-Z][\w._-/&&[^()]]*\z`. Have never coded in Python/am not really familiar with it, and I can't figure out how to translate this over. Thank you.

Comment: What is this regex for?

Comment: You can refer to this site, https://regexr.com/

Comment: What happened when you tried this regular expressiohn in Python? Any errors?

Comment: This regex won't work in Java. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash A work wikipedia article.

Comment: possible differences from Python: `\A` in Java regex means "beginning of input", `\z` means "end of input"... Python regex has `\A`, same meaning, but only `\Z` (seems same as `\Z` in Java, slightly different meaning to `\z`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Errors I get are: PEP 8: W605 invalid escape sequence '\A', '\w', '\z'

Comment: @Anentropic thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: This can be the converted one. `(?m)^[a-zA-Z]((?![()])[-\w./])*$`.According to what I figured out; your regex tests a string which starts with the letter and  contain `-\w./` zero or more times but does not contain `()`.

Comment: @Mandy8055 i could not transfer through the computer the amount of appreciation i have for you right now

Comment: No worries @alexkirigiya....I'm glad I could help =)

Comment: That's not even a valid Java regex because the range `_-/` isn't a valid range

Comment: @alexkirigiya the errors you're getting for escaped characters likely has to do with not using the raw string literal: `r'regex goes here'`

Comment: @ctwheels; I guess [**intersection class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) is not supported in python regex flavor too. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Mandy8055 it's not. I can't provide an ideal regex without a proper range either (OP's regex isn't valid)

Comment: in this case the intersection class is not required: the `&&[^()]` in the java regex means "everything in the outer class _except_ for `(` and `)`"... but the parens are not captured by the outer character class (they are not matched by `\w`) so you could safely omit the `&&[^()]` part

Comment: assuming a literal `-` was intended rather than a char range then: `r"\A[a-zA-Z][\w._\-/]*\Z"`  works, but note the minor semantic difference between Java's `\z` and Python's `\Z`

Comment: (escaping the `-` as `\-` is needed in the Java version too, as written currently it is invalid in Java because `_-/` means a char range, but is not a valid one... try it here http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgIDSvseLCgw/index.html)